# Require is not recognised in NodeJS application

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, express, require

I have followed the steps from here http://expressjs.com/en/starter/installing.html to install express NodeJS application. After installing we moved to "myapp" directory and then we have installed "aws-iot-device-sdk" from https://github.com/aws/aws-iot-device-sdk-js.

Here in node_modules directory aws-iot-device-sdk directory was created.

In public directory we have started exploring with an example by creating "index.html". After starting NodeJS server in browser we tried to open http://localhost:3000, Here index.html screen got opened.

**index.html** - Script tag we are requiring "aws-iot-device-sdk" to run AWS - IOT application but here we are getting following error.

> Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined

Below is the code of index.html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script>
function clicked(){
var awsIot = require('aws-iot-device-sdk');
    }
</script>
<body>
<input type="submit" onclick="clicked()" value="Click here to send email">
</body>
</html>
```

to redirect to index.html we have used below code in app.js

```
app.use(express.static('public'));
```

Please help me in this issue.

Thanks,
Rakesh Kalwa.

Comment: Can you update your question with the stacktrace as well as the bit of code that causes that error? There should be a line file and line number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long research i got solved the issue by adding "ejs" into NodeJS application. Here now i am able to call Require in browser.

Now we are able to access **AWS-IOT from Browser**.

Comment: Can you please have a look at my AWS IoT question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35823058/aws-iot-describe-endpointyou-must-specify-a-region

Comment: Thanks Mona for reply but in my case i am able to get the region but my question is in connecting HTML browser with NodeJS. Where i am using REQUIRE in javascript.

Answer (score 2):

The *aws-iot-device-sdk* module is designed to be run via node.

Node has a built in `require` method but this is not available natively in a browser (which is why the error says *'require is not defined'*).

In order to `require` a model in client side code, you would need to use a module loader such as [require.js](http://requirejs.org/)

In this case though, the *aws-iot-device-sdk* module dependencies mean it will **only** run via node.

Depending on what you are trying to achieve, you probably want to implement an API in node that can work with the AWS module, and call it from your client-side code.

Comment: Yes, we trying to call AWS API's in browser using NodeJS application. As per your comment i have installed  **npm install requirejs** and tried again starting NodeJS server, But same issue repeated.

Comment: Simply installing require.js will not solve your problem. You need to actually configure and use it in your front-end application. Please read http://requirejs.org/docs/start.html

Comment: However, in your case, the require is irrelevant - you need to build a client side app (with or without require.js), and use it to call a node app that requires the AWS module.

Comment: Thanks @duncanhall, I have tried using requirejs to configure in my node js application. Here i tried to define the dependencies in index.js as `define(['aws-iot-device-sdk'], function(awsIot)` here it is expecting **aws-iot-device-sdk** as .js file. But its a folder how should i handle this situation. Html screen i am getting error as `Uncaught Error: Script error for "aws-iot-device-sdk", needed by: index` as it is trying to load .js file.